# Question about kernel and homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was wondering is there any reason we take the identity e` for the kernel for ring homomorphism to be the additive identity instead of the multiplicative one?

Comment: Well, there are a number of reasons. But one very persuasive one, I imagine, is that if you take the kernel to be the set of elements that map to the multiplicative identity, you (in many cases) no longer have an ideal. That is, if $\phi(r)=\phi(s)=1$, then $\phi(r+s)=\phi(r)+\phi(s)=1+1$, which may not be (and often is not) $1$, so the kernel is no longer additively closed.

Comment: Another reason is that in general a ring is not required to have a multiplicative inverse. Rings that do are called unital rings. Mathematicians have defined ring homomorphisms so that one definition works for all rings.

Comment: @neuguy you mean that in general a ring is not required to have a multiplicative identity. Anyway, a majority of authors do require this, and might call what you call a ring a rng.

Comment: Another reason I see is that, when considering the ring as an additive group, the definition is consistent with the definition of the kernel for group homomorphisms.

Comment: @KevinCarlson if that's a joke and you came up with it I have to congratulate you.

Comment: It might have originated as a pun, vis, a rng being a "ring without i", but it's actual terminology. And it certainly didn't originate with me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)

Comment: @KevinCarlson Oops, typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is that the idea kernels in general works best with *groups*.

For a group homomorphism $f$ the kernel tells us something interesting about what happens to elements under $f$, namely that $f(a)=f(b)$ exactly when $ab^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $f$. This relation depends on taking the inverse of either $a$ or $b$, so it doesn't work well if we try to use it with something else than a group, where elements may not have inverses in general.

Kernels work for *rings*, *vector spaces* and so forth because these structures can all be described as an *abelian group* with some extra structure. In the case of a ring, the additive group is the only group structure in sight, so if we want to speak of kernels, it is the identity element of that group we want the preimage of.

If we're speaking of *fields* we *almost* have a multiplicative group -- but not quite; 0 is not a member of the multiplicative group. And speaking of kernels is not very relevant in the case of fields anyway, because a field homomorphism is necessarily injective, so having an object that tells us when $f(a)=f(b)$ is not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a line of reasoning that leads to this definition of kernel: among groups, one has the isomorphism $G/\text{ker}\varphi\cong \text{im}\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is any homomorphism out of $G$. This is a constantly useful theorem, so we'd like something equivalent for rings. And it's the usual definition of kernel as the inverse image of zero that gets us this theorem. As commenters have mentioned, this rests on the fact that the kernel is an ideal, so that $R/\text{ker}\varphi$ is at least a ring; in contrast the inverse image of the multiplicative identity is just some multiplicative submonoid of $R$, so that the best kind of isomorphism theorem you could get out such a "kernel" would be an isomorphism of monoids. And that's not very useful.

Comment: This reasoning seems to suppose that we have a concept of quotient before we start speaking of kernels. While this is certainly formally possible, it feels more straightforward to me to start by introducing kernels as a way to encode how much a homomorphism fails to be injective, and _then_ motivate quotients as a way to construct a (surjective) homomorphism with a given kernel.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's an interesting perspective, and either direction seems possible to me. I probably wouldn't motivate quotients that way myself, rather than in terms of, say, relations.